# Pad a number with prefix zeros no and decimal place in Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel-2007, formatting

Is there a way of formatting cells to:

1. Add zeros to fill entered numbers that fall short of the required amount.
2. Not round up/down decimal places but display as an entered number.

For example, if I input `100.50`, I would like the formatted number to be `000010050`. I am using a custom cell format of `000000000` which works great for whole numbers but rounds the decimal place to display `100.50` as `000000101`.

Answer (score 0):

You will need a formula to convert to text, remove the decimal (don't forget to cope with other number formatting if the sheet will be used in countries that swap . and ,) and left pad with the usual:

```
=RIGHT("00000000"&REPLACE( A1, FIND(".", A1), 1, ""), 9)
```

Note that I've not actually tested the above. Also note A1 should be whatever cell you want to change.

Ah, just realised that the above doesn't allow for trailing zero's either so you would need to fix that.

Comment: Great, thank you for the quick response.  I used =SUBSTITUTE(A1,".","")*1 which seems to be doing the trick.  Thanks so much for getting me on the right track :)